# This is an assignment I have to turn in. I am missing something about the function calculation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have three test scores the lowest score will be dropped. A function is used to calculate the final grade and the grade has to be converted from a number to a letter. I have done everything I can I am trying to figure out and make sure that the function is written correctly.

```
'I put these at public class so they could be used throughout the program

Dim test1 As Double
Dim test2 As Double
Dim test3 As Double
Dim student As String
Dim Result1 As String
Dim total As String


Function SemesterGrade(ByVal t1 As Double, ByVal t2 As Double, ByVal t3 As Double) As Double

    'This function determines the test scores and drops the lowest score from calculation
    If t1 < t2 And t1 < t3 Then
        total = CStr(((t2 + t3) / 2))

    ElseIf t2 < t3 And t2 < t1 Then
        total = CStr(((test1 + test3) / 2))

    ElseIf t3 < t2 And t3 < t1 Then
        total = CStr(((t1 + t2) / 2))

        'I added this if statement to calculate if all the scores were the same because the program would not give me the correct output 
    ElseIf t1 = t2 And t2 = t3 Then
        total = CStr((t1 + t2 + t3) / 3)

    End If

    'this returns the result from this function
    Return CDbl(total)



End Function

Private Sub btnDetermine_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDetermine.Click
    Dim result As String
    'these pull the information from my textboxes 
    test1 = CDbl(txtFirst.Text)
    test2 = CDbl(txtSecond.Text)
    test3 = CDbl(txtThird.Text)
    student = txtName.Text.ToUpper

    'this is how i use the function calculation 
    result = CStr((SemesterGrade(test1, test2, test3)))

    'This is to convert the number score to a letter
    If CDbl(total) >= 90 Then
        Result1 = ("A")
    ElseIf CDbl(total) >= 80 Then
        Result1 = "B"
    ElseIf CDbl(total) >= 70 Then
        Result1 = "C"
    ElseIf CDbl(total) >= 60 Then
        Result1 = "D"
    ElseIf CDbl(total) < 60 Then
        Result1 = "F"

    End If

    'This is the output for the result 
    txtResult.Text = student & ": " & Result1


End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling your function into a variable and comparing another variable. Replace the below part and retry;

```
'this is how i use the function calculation 
result = (SemesterGrade(test1, test2, test3))

'This is to convert the number score to a letter
If result >= 90 Then
    Result1 = ("A")
ElseIfresult >= 80 Then
    Result1 = "B"
ElseIf result  >= 70 Then
    Result1 = "C"
ElseIf result >= 60 Then
    Result1 = "D"
ElseIf result < 60 Then
    Result1 = "F"
End If
```